# client telnet ansi tag color

Tags: ios, objective-c

my code is a simple telnet client, i have a UItextview to see the input stream of my telnet server.
My problem is when my telnet server send a stream with color tag i see :

outpu t= [37m[2J[34m myText

i think it's an "ansi" format problem

this is my stream input code:

```
  -(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

   switch (streamEvent) {

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:

               NSLog(@"Stream opened");

        break;

    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

        if (theStream == inputStream) {

            uint8_t buffer[1024];

            int len;

            while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {

                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];

                if (len > 0) {

                 output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len 

                            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    if (nil != output) {

                        NSLog(@"output=%@",output);

                        [self envoiDonnees];

                    }

                }

            }

        }

          break;
```

is there a way to see the color in my Uitextview monitor?
Or a way to filter the color tag to don't see it

by advance thank's

Comment: You want to do some reading on regular expressions if you need to filter out that tags